# === won't work even if the statement is true

Tags: javascript

```
var age =prompt("What is your age?");

if (age === 21) {
 console.log("Happy 21st Birthday!");
}
```

When I write 21 in the prompt, it gives me an undefined, if I replace the === with == then it will work. Why? 21 is the same type and value as the 21 I write in the prompt

Comment: Do you know the difference between == and === ?

Comment: prompt will get a string and you are comparing number with a string. that's why your condition became false.  == checks if the value of the variable is equal. === checks if the value and type are equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `age` gets a `String` from the `prompt`.
For it to work you need to convert it to an `int` with the operator `+`:

If the use of the `+` operator feels strange to you in this case, you can always use the function [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) instead. It will achieve the same result.

```js
var age = +prompt("What is your age?");
//        ^ Converts your String to an int
if (age === 21) {
 console.log("Happy 21st Birthday!");
}
```

Comment: parseInt() might be better for a beginner rather than using short hand

Comment: I see many people not knowing about the shorthand, even advanced ones. I try to advertise it as much as possible :)

Comment: @AndrewBone I don't see a problem with it, its an answer at the end of the day and I managed to learn something new today. Thanks Zenoo.

Comment: Good point. It might be worth editing your answer to have both, your call though 

Comment: @AndrewBone I agree, was just about to suggest adding both methods and possibly a link to documentation for the shorthand.

Comment: I edited my answer to fulfill both your requests. I can't seem to find any doc on the shorthand for some reason, though.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt() function returns a string. You check for an integer.

Basically `==` checks if the value of the variable is equal.

`===` checks if the value and type is equal.

You can find more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

`===` is check the `value` and `type` of variable and `prompt` return `string value` thats why `===` return false because `prompt return string 21` and you compare with `int 21` so return `false`

so below to way to get your output using `==` or `string to int conversion`

```js
var age = prompt("What is your age?");

if (age == 21) {
  console.log("Happy 21st Birthday!");
}

//OR

if (parseInt(age) === 21) {
  console.log("Happy 21st Birthday!");
}
```